# Guarantee order of promise running, Word API JS

Tags: javascript, ms-word, promise, ms-office, office-js

I'm working on a Word Add-In and need to replace a large number of codes throughout a document with values fetched from an API. I'm new to promises and am having issues getting the replacements to run sequentially so positions aren't disrupted causing replacements to be missed. My best stab at this so far is this:

```
function merge(documentFieldKeys) {
    if (documentFieldKeys.length > 0)
        Word.run(function(context) {
            var key = documentFieldKeys.shift();
            var results = context.document.body.search(key.Code, { matchWholeWord: false, matchCase: false });
            context.load(results);
            return context.sync().then(function() {
                    if (results.items.length > 0 && key.Value === "") {
                        missingFields.push(key.Description);
                    } else {
                        for (var i = 0; i < results.items.length; i++) {
                            results.items[i].insertText(key.Value, "replace");
                        }
                    }
                })
                .then(context.sync).then(merge(documentFieldKeys));
        });
}
```

Based on my understanding of promises, it should process the first item and then once complete pass the shorted list for another replacement. However, they are going in a seemingly random order. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: `.then(merge(documentFieldKeys))` => `.then(function() { return merge(documentFieldKeys); })` - because you need to pass a function to .then, not whatever a function returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `.then(merge(documentFieldKeys))`.  It means you're invoking the merge function immediately.  What you want to do is instead:

`.then(function() {
    return merge(documentFieldKeys);
})
.then(context.sync);`

**Update:**

Note:  The second `.then(context.sync)` is optional, you don't actually need it, because `Word.run` will flush the queue at the end anyway.  But I find it cleaner to show it.

Also, for what it's worth:  I've written a book about Office.js, "[Building Office Add-ins using Office.js](https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins)".  In it I include a long primer on Promises, as well as TypeScript and `async/await`, which makes working with Promises much easier.  The book is available in e-book form at https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins, with [all profits to charity](http://buildingofficeaddins.com/charity).

Comment: why would you need to reverse the order of the last two .then?

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft  Thanks, that worked. I'll definitely check out that book as I'm sure our client will want more done other than this port to the Web API once this is done.